# How do I pad a string length in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I use javascript to get a string (name) that I will eventually paste to a text file with other data (a grade).

```
var name = "Joe Smith";
var n = str.length;
document.getElementById("sum").value="" + name + " " + grade
```

I want to create a column effect that will make the text file easier to read by reading the length of the name string then adding a number of spaces relative to the length of the str variable.

So, if the string length is 15 spaces, I will add 5 spaces to make it 20.  And if the string length is 10, I will add 10 spaces to make it 20 too.  When I use the PRE tag, all the grade variables should line up.

Should I use the join() function somehow? I'm not sure how.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for your attention.  With respect, I believe I am attempting to do something much more simple.  I want to add spaces to the right side of variable name.  I can't seem to extract an answer that will help me from that questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("sum").value = name + Array(20 - name.length).join(" ") + grade
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks! Commodore Vic-20 forever!

Answer (score 1):

As a function:

```
var name = "Joe Smith";

// give it a string and a number of total spaces
function pad(str, n) {
    return str + Array(n - str.length).join(" ");
}

document.write(pad(name, 20));
```